# How to check and turn off all my listening local web server ports on OS X?

Tags: localhost, webserver, port, firewall

I got an error in my osx CLI:

```
WARNING: Failed to start a local web server listening on any port between 8085 and 8186. Please check your firewall settings or locally running programs that may be blocking or using those ports.
```

How to check and see or turn off any app that is running between  8085 and 8186 ports?

I did: `sudo lsof -i -P` and I couldn't find anything between those ports.

Any help, please?

Thanks for your help and time!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem but finally fixed it by gcloud network diagnostics all passed.
Have you passed all the network diagnostics checking during "gcloud init"?
please check if you are using VPN or proxies and close it.
You may not skip network diagnostics when you first run gcloud init locally.